# unable to login to Azure when setting up website in Visual Studio using MSDN

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I get the error below when trying to setup a new Visual studio 2013 (community) web site with the Azure option chosen. However, I am able to login to the Azure manage portal and view resources etc. I have had similar login problems when login in via browser as well.

My subscription is VS Pro with MSDN. Has anyone encountered or got a solution? (technical support is not free under this sub)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The article at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2015/01/08/issue-related-to-signing-while-accessing-microsoft-azure-resources-from-visual-studio-2013-update-4.aspx should help resolve the issue.

**Workaround 1**

1. Right click on the "Azure" node in VS Server Explorer, and then click "Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription...".
2. If a dialog appears saying you are already signed in with an account, click OK to sign out.
3. Sign in with the desired account.

**Workaround 2**

1. Right click on the "Azure" node in VS Server Explorer, and then click "Manage Subscriptions...".
2. In the "Manage Microsoft Azure Subscriptions" dialog, click the "Sign Out" button on the "Subscriptions" tab if you are already signed in.
3. Close the dialog, and then close Visual Studio.
4. Open Windows File Explorer, navigate to "This PC -> Documents -> Visual Studio 2013 -> Settings" folder.
5. You will see the file "Windows Azure Subscriptions.xml". Rename or delete the file.
6. Start Visual Studio again.
7. Right click the "Azure" node in VS Server Explorer, and then select "Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription...".
8. Sign in with the desired account.